# split a string in python on linebreaks

Tags: python, split

I have a tuple with a string of times and activities.  So, it would be similar to this:

```
('08:01: Woke Up\n08:05: Took Shower\n08:20: Ate Breakfast\n08:45: Left for work', )
```

I need to be able to take each activity and display individually like so:

```
8:01 Woke Up
8:05 Took Shower
8:20 Ate Breakfast
8:45 Left for work
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion for the best/easiest way to do this in python?  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *already* have newlines in the element, so just print that:

```
>>> tup = ('08:01: Woke Up\n08:05: Took Shower\n08:20: Ate Breakfast\n08:45: Left for work',)
>>> print tup[0]
08:01: Woke Up
08:05: Took Shower
08:20: Ate Breakfast
08:45: Left for work
```

You can split out the string into separate elements by using [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
>>> tup[0].splitlines()
['08:01: Woke Up', '08:05: Took Shower', '08:20: Ate Breakfast', '08:45: Left for work']
>>> for line in tup[0].splitlines():
...     print line
... 
08:01: Woke Up
08:05: Took Shower
08:20: Ate Breakfast
08:45: Left for work
```

Should you require the times and activities as separate strings, split each line on the string `': '`:

```
>>> for line in tup[0].splitlines():
...     time, activity = line.split(': ', 1)
...     print time, activity
... 
08:01 Woke Up
08:05 Took Shower
08:20 Ate Breakfast
08:45 Left for work
```

Comment: Great answer. And if you want to split each line up into a time and an activity, you can do `line.split(None, 1)` or `line.partition(' ')`.

Comment: @abarnert: splitting on `': '`, actually; now my output matches the question sample.

Comment: Very detailed and spot on answer.  Thank you, and thanks to the other responses as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, that works, but I'm not sure it's more readable; you have to think about the fact that the first colon doesn't count because it doesn't have a space after it…

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> t = ('08:01: Woke Up\n08:05: Took Shower\n08:20: Ate Breakfast\n08:45: Left for work', )
>>> for elem in t:
...     print elem.split('\n')
...
['08:01: Woke Up', '08:05: Took Shower', '08:20: Ate Breakfast', '08:45: Left fo
r work']
>>> for elem in t:
...     for activity in elem.split('\n'):
...             print activity
...
08:01: Woke Up
08:05: Took Shower
08:20: Ate Breakfast
08:45: Left for work
>>> for elem in t:
...     print elem
...
08:01: Woke Up
08:05: Took Shower
08:20: Ate Breakfast
08:45: Left for work
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a tuple, you have a string which, if you print,  will give you precisely what you want.

Supposing you had a list of tuples (which I assume is what you meant) you should do something like this:

```
input = [("8:01", "Woke Up"), ("8:05", "Took shower"), ("8:20", "Ate Breakfast")]
for time, description in input:
  print time, description
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever thought of dictionaries? You could store the time information as key and the activity as value, as such:

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary['8:01'] = 'Woke Up'
dictionary['8:05'] = 'Took Shower'
dictionary['8:20'] = 'Ate Breakfast'
dictionary['8:45'] = 'Left for work'
```

Then to print in the format you could simply do:

```
for k in dictionary:
    print k + ' ' + dictionary[k]
```